# Unable to apply both "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" and "Theme.AppCompat.Light" at the same time

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am using

```
<style name="MyThemeActionbar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="colorAccent">#0d786e</item>
</style>
```

and also

```
<style name="MyThemeActionbar1" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:statusBarColor">#003300</item>

    </style>
```

this style globally . Both are not working at a time. May I know why?

Comment: please specify "not working" and show us how you assign those themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a test app with your themes:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    theme: "MyThemeActionbar1"
});

var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: "open"
});

btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        theme: "MyThemeActionbar"
    });
    win2.open();

})
win.add(btn);
win.open();
```

is working fine for me.

Theme file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyThemeActionbar1" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#003300</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyThemeActionbar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorAccent">#0d786e</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: actually, I wanna use   both the parent styles in a single window

Comment: only if i use "appcompat.light" the switch is looking good and also the "noactionbar "style to hide the action bar . hence i want both to be in single window

Comment: Try using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as a parent

Answer (score 0):

I changed the parent style which was written separately as Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar it worked for my scenario exactly the way i wanted.